SignOutAsync() wont delete application cookie when custom domain is configured
Im using ASP.NET Core Identity for authentication and authorization.
Because I want users to login on mysite.com and be able to access subdomain.mysite.com without logging in again, I configured my key storage provider (for both applications) to persist their keys to a shared database:
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToDbContext<MySharedDbContext>()
    .SetApplicationName("MySite");

And then configured the application cookie to use the upper level domain name:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = ".mysite.com";
});

This is pretty simple and just works. However, users can't logout any longer. The logout method is:
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}

The only way I can get the authentication cookie to be cleared is by doing it manually and adding this call to the logout method:
Response.Cookies.Append(".AspNet.SharedCookie", "", new CookieOptions
{
    Domain = Program.GlobalSettings.CookieDomain,
    Expires = DateTimeOffset.MinValue,
});

This seems like a bug though, because the Identity service knows what domain the application cookie was set on (hell, it did it by itself!) so surely when _signInManager.SignOutAsync() is called it should also know how to clear that cookie?

Hi Jimbo, please let me know the solution works for you ot not? If the issue still occurs, please share your 2 project Program.cs files with us, I will check them.

Single sign-on user logout operation does not require additional cookie expiration code.
Make sure your mysite.com and subdomain.mysite.com apps have below settings.
// App1 and App2, all the apps should add below settings

builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\"))
    .SetApplicationName("MyTestSharedCookieApp");

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = ".mysite.com";
});

// App1 and App2, all the apps should add  settings above

My Test Result

Click logout

Refresh App1 Page

Suggestion
If all the apps has settings above and still not works, then we can consider save dataprotection in local like builder.Services.AddDataProtection() .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\shared-auth-ticket-keys\")).

Hi Jason. I'd already configured both my applications per your suggestion, albeit using PersistKeysToDbContext instead of file system because the applications do not share a file system.
I know that PersistKeysToDbContext is working because I can log in on one and be authenticated on both, its just the logout which is causing a problem.

Hi @Jimbo As you know, it's working by using the basic template, could you create a brand new sample which can reproduce the issue for me without any sensitive information.

@Jimbo I'm willing to figure out what happen in this case, thanks for your understanding. I will reply you next Monday when I am free. Thanks for your understanding, have a nice weekend.
